# Preloading ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer on pan

Tags: zooming, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

When I pan the map with the mouse, I want the visible layers to update (before I release the mouse). Ideally, it would actually be preloaded, like the basemaps, so that you don't have to see the unloaded edge of the layers.

Example: Say I have a layer which is a solid red block over the entire map. When I pan, the screen moves so that you see that the red layer doesn't extend to infinity; it's actually covering only the viewport. It now appears as a rectangle which is moving around the screen as you pan, until you release.  I want the user to be able to pan and only ever see red. This is a contrived example, but it's the functionality I want.

What doesn't work: I have already tried running a layer.refresh() command on the map's pan event. That won't work until after you release the mouse.

Comment: add your code here.... create fiddler if possible...

Comment: @VikashPandey Thanks, but I don't have any code, because I'm asking for direction on what layer type might do what I want for example.

Comment: I have added below hints.. you can consider that as base to start...

Answer (score 1):

Well, As I am understanding above requirement. you want to add a layer on the ESRI map; which will refresh every time you pan or zoom.

In this case no need to add the layer as **ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer**. Simply add the layer as a **feature layer** in **ondemand mode**.

To know about feature layer and its mode [please click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html)

As we know it request to update layer automatically whenever you change extent of the map.

Hoping I gave you the hint which you are looking for... :)